# Exists any way to generate JSON declaration from a typescript class?

Tags: json, typescript

Example

```
class A {
       constructor(public val1: number, public val2: number,public val3: string, public b: B) {
 }
}

class B {
       constructor(public val4: boolean, public val5: number) {
 }
}
```

exists any function that receives class A and return the JSON structure of the class, not matter if it's just visual, return this:

```
{val1: number, val2: number, val3: string, b: {val4: boolean, val5: number}}
```

a class in typescript it's no more that a hash of {nameProperty:data type, ...}

I want the class that only have properties,  has not methods.

Comment: That's incorrect, classes in typescript do have (or can have) functions (which are then methods), and they are not just "a hash of {nameProperty:data type, ...}", maybe you are referring to interfaces. In your example the classes don't even have any members (you'll need to add `public` for the args to be members). And even if you did, the properties of a class aren't part of the prototype, only the instance so you can't get them form a class.

Comment: I am sorry you are right, I have will add public to all properties, I forget it

Comment: I know that classes in typescript can have functions, but I say that my class only will have properties, I'm sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

I'll better explain what I wrote in my comment.

In typescript when you define a class you need to define the members in it, but when it's compiled to js the members aren't really being added to the class.

Consider the following typescript:

```
class A {
    str: string;
    num: number;
}
```

It compiles to:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A() {
    }
    return A;
}());
```

As you can see there's no trace of the `str` and `num` members in the js code.
When you assign values:

```
class A {
    constructor(public str: string, public num: number) {}
}
```

It compiles to:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A(str, num) {
        this.str = str;
        this.num = num;
    }
    return A;
}());
```

Here you can see `str` and `num`, but notice that they are added to the instance in the constructor, they are not added to the prototype (unlike methods) or to `A`, so there's no way to access them until you have an instance.

Because of that you can not get a mapping of properties in a class.
You can use the [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata) package to save the members meta data.

Comment: I understand, there is not way of get data type of properties and represent it in hash

Comment: I find this extension for vscode with that functionality, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MariusAlchimavicius.json-to-ts, it does with interfaces but is very useful.